# Configure TP-LINK router to broadcast my network IP address

Tags: windows

I have a TP-Link model:TL-WR1043ND which I want to use in my network of 172.23.5... but when ever I connect it broadcast 192.168.1.1 network to all client that connect as the result, they can't access the map drive of the server. I want to set it up so that it will broadcast the ip of my network I am using DHCP

Answer (score 0):

the manual is availabe here: http://tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WR1043ND_V1_User_Guide.pdf
and the section on configuring DHCP starts on page 55. see figure 4.7.1 for the screen you would use to set your dhcp pool start and end addresses.